# how to convert multilevel index rows to multilevel index columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

As shown in the image attached, I would like to convert how the dataframe is arranged.

I tried:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.columns])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(index.shape), index=index, columns=['value'])
```

but got an error saying " isna is not defined for MultiIndex"?

How to fix this?

Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `stack()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html

Comment: gees... it is so easy when you know how to do it. I spent a lot of time to concatenate dataframes etc.  Thanks!  df.stack(level=0) worked!